# Como posicionar um formulário a direita da tela?

Tags: html

Essa imagem mostra o formulário que quero posicionar.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfdVv.jpg)

Comment: display: flex; justify-conent: flex-end; ou float: right;

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com `float: right;`

```css
.direita{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<form class="direita">
    Nome: <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!